# Filtering out a group from a Teradata / SQL statement originated from a concatenate

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata, having

I concatenated the year and month values of a date and I'm trying to exclude one combination from the output with a HAVING statement. However, it continues to show up.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) || EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS yearmonth, SUM(amt)
FROM trnsact
GROUP BY yearmonth
HAVING yearmonth<>'2005 8'
;
```

I started using != in the HAVING statement but the Teradata documentation suggested to use any of the following:

```
<>
^=
NE
NOT=
```

I've tried all of them and the group that I'm trying to exclude still shows up. I also tried using a WHERE statement instead.

I know I could avoid the concatenate and just create two conditions but I would like to understand why is this route not working and hopefully fix it!

Why is the WHERE or HAVING not filtering out concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually better to do this in a `where` clause (before aggregation) than in the `having` clause.  So, just use the `extract` value or date arithmetic:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) || EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS yearmonth,
       SUM(amt)
FROM trnsact
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) <> 2005 or EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) <> 8
GROUP BY monthyear;
```

I think it is more natural to write as:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) || EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS yearmonth,
       SUM(amt)
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate < date '2005-08-01' or saledate >= '2005-09-01'
GROUP BY monthyear;
```

Comment: The output shows '2005 8', not '200508', '20058', nor yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Still interested in knowing why the concatenate doesn't get filtered.

Comment: I can only guess that something is wrong with your query.  In one part, you use `yearmonth` and in another `monthyear`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I made an edit to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Still having the same issue. Is there any incompatibility between the format of the concatenate and the criteria given to the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever check the actual result?

When you concat two numeric values there's an implicit (automatic) typecast to string using the default `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT  '#' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE) || '#'
```

returns

```
#       2016          2#
```

Those extra blanks are based on the default `FORMAT` for integers.

The easiest way to get the extpected result is to add an explicit cast:

```
SELECT to_char(saledate, 'yyyy mm')
```

But why do you want a string output? Either two columns

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate), EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)
```

or an integer are more efficient:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) * 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS yearmonth
```

Of course, you better move the condition into `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.

Comment: Thanks for that, those will definitely be much better ways of arriving to the result I'm looking for.

Comment: But still, what would be the best way of matching the format result of the concatenate? Is there any way I could add those blanks to the condition?

Comment: @DanSan: to_char(saledate, 'yyyy mm') returns a string with 4 digits, a space, two digits with a leading zero, so `where yearmonth <> '2005 08'` will match. If you want a different string change the format...

Answer (score 0):

There is also discussion in the Coursera forum and replied by one of the mentor:
"You can't assume that the format of the joined year month is '2005 8'. This is a common mistake. I prefer simply to exclude all data after 31 July 2005 but you can also use AND/ OR tests. If you want to use the joined text you can do
WHERE YEAR_MONTH<>'EXTRACT(YEAR from '2005-08-01')||EXTRACT(MONTH from '2005-08-01')"